# Website javascript program cannot be executed smoothly

Tags: javascript

I made a website with score calculation function
Enter grades numbered 1 to 5
Then use the javascript array to calculate the average score of the scores numbered 1 to 5
But my website can’t calculate the average grade
I hope you can provide assistance and advice
Thank you everyone
My code:

```js
function aes() {
  let sum = 0;
  let scoresum = 0;
  score.forEach(function(element.index));
  scoresum += element["score"];
  document.getElementById("ans").value = scoresum / 5;
})
```

```css
p {
  font-family: standard italics;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr style="height: 50px;">
    <td style="width: 100px;">
      <p>Number</p>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100px;">
      <p>Total score</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 50px;">
    <td style="width: 100px;">
      <p>1</p>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100px;"> <input type="text" id="score" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 50px;">
    <td style="width: 100px;">
      <p>2</p>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100px;"> <input type="text" id="score" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 50px;">
    <td style="width: 100px;">
      <p>3</p>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100px;"> <input type="text" id="score" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 50px;">
    <td style="width: 100px;">
      <p>4</p>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100px;"> <input type="text" id="score" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 50px;">
    <td style="width: 100px;">
      <p>5</p>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100px;"> <input type="text" id="score" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 50px;">
    <td style="width: 100px;">
      <p>Average</p>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100px;"><input type="text" id="ans" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"> </td>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="scs" onclick="aes()">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you see what errors you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Some mistakes you had:

- you can't reuse `id`s in a document
- your HTML was invalidly structured
- you should use classes instead of repeating inline styles
- your JavaScript had syntax errors (I basically rewrote it)

```js
function aes() {
  let count = 0;
  let sum = 0;
  [...document.querySelectorAll("input.score")].forEach((el) => {
    const val = parseFloat(el.value);
    if(!Number.isNaN(val)) {
      count++;
      sum += val;
    }
  });
  document.getElementById("ans").value = sum / count; 
}
```

```css
tr {
  height: 50px;
}
input.score {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Number</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>Total score</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>1</p>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="score"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>2</p>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="score"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>3</p>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="score"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>4</p>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="score"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>5</p>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" class="score"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Average</p>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="ans" readonly></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="submit" id="scs" onclick="aes()">
```